# Firebase remote config minimum interval time

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am working on firebase remote config from web and mobile react native. While working on I have come across the following [statement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=ios#throttling):

> During app development,you might want to fetch more often to refresh
> the cache very frequently (many times per hour) to let you rapidly
> iterate as you develop and test your app. Real-time Remote Config
> updates automatically bypass the cache when the config is updated on
> the server. To accommodate rapid iteration on a project with numerous
> developers, you can temporarily add a FIRRemoteConfigSettings property
> with a low minimum fetch interval (MinimumFetchInterval) in your app.
>
> The default and recommended production fetch interval for Remote
> Config is 12 hours, which means that configs won't be fetched from the
> backend more than once in a 12 hour window, regardless of how many
> fetch calls are actually made. Specifically, the minimum fetch
> interval is determined in this following order:
>
> 1. The parameter in `fetch(long)`
> 2. The parameter in `FIRRemoteConfigSettings.MinimumFetchInterval` hours
> 3. The default value of 12
>
> Keep in mind that this setting should be used for development only,
> not for an app running in production. If you're just testing your app
> with a small 10-person development team, you are unlikely to hit the
> hourly service-side quota limits. But if you pushed your app out to
> thousands of test users with a very low minimum fetch interval, your
> app would probably hit this quota.

What does the statement "Keep in mind that this setting should be used for development only, not for an app running in production" mean?

Does this imply that we should avoid setting the minimum fetch time in the production environment and setting the minimum fetch time interval(<12) solely for development testing? I have noticed in other inquiries that some suggest reducing the 12-hour interval to 1 hour. Is it acceptable to set a 1-hour interval, and if so, how does the count work? Is it counted for each device with the app installed or based on all calls made from my app?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.  In your case, you should use a blockquote to quote the text you copy from the docs. You should also consider providing a link to where you saw this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more frequent updates of your remote configuration for your production users than every few hours, I recommend implementing [real-time updates for Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started#add-real-time-listener) instead of a polling based workaround.

Comment: At the moment, I can't afford to update my Firebase-related libraries(updating the remote config to a newer version will lead to updating other Firebase libraries). So is it okay to go with a 1-hour interval to production? and how the request count works with remote config?